# How to set a video height to be full screen less the size of the header?

Tags: html, css

I have a video placed inside a div, that I want to be at the full size of the screen less the size of the header, which is 50px; So say the user has a screen size of 600 px, I want the video to be 550px. How would I do this?

Thanks
DcoltGaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `calc` CSS function.

```css
target{
  height: calc(100vh - 50px)
}
```